# Yii2 how to call post function

Tags: post, yii2

In a Yii2 form I nee to trigger some code when things changed on a field
I'm using onchange to do this

This is the kind of thing I need :

```
->dropDownList(Customer::getDataList(), [
    'prompt' => Yii::t('app','select.customer'), 
    'onchange' => '$.post("index.php?r=comptacust/selectedlists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("select#invoiceheader-comptacust_id").html(data);
    })', 
    'onchange' => '$.post("index.php?r=pmtmode/selectedlists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("select#invoiceheader-pmtmode_id").html(data);
    })', 
    'onchange' => '$.post("index.php?r=pmtcondition/selectedlists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("select#invoiceheader-pmtcondition_id").html(data);
    })',
]);
```

But the post function does work only 1 time (for pmtcondition)

What do I need to do so that I can do the 3 posts ?

Any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is just substituting the `onchange` value in your `dropDownList`, so you need to add the js code in one `onchange` assignment:

```
->dropDownList(Customer::getDataList(), [
    'prompt' => Yii::t('app','select.customer'), 
    'onchange' => '
        $.post("index.php?r=comptacust/selectedlists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("select#invoiceheader-comptacust_id").html(data);
        });
        $.post("index.php?r=pmtmode/selectedlists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("select#invoiceheader-pmtmode_id").html(data);
        });
        $.post("index.php?r=pmtcondition/selectedlists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("select#invoiceheader-pmtcondition_id").html(data);
        });
    ',
]);
```